# What was Sabine Schmitz saying when she introduced The Stig in German?

Tags: translation, top-gear

In Series 23 Episode 3 of Top Gear when they hand the Audi R8 over to The Stig, there was the customary introduction / joke. On this occasion it was delivered by Sabine Schmitz, in German.

Unfortunately my German is rustier than a 25 year old Alfa Romeo so I didn't understand what was said. Can someone provide a translation?

Comment: Sabine Schmitz (14.5.1969 – 16.3.2021) passed away Tuesday after her brave fight against cancer. She was 51 years old.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sabine Schmitz introduces the Stig with the following words:

> Some say, *es ist der Mann, der auch ein Rennfahrer ist. Er hat zwei … Füße!*

which translates into English as

> Some say, it is the man who is also a racing driver. He has got two … feet!

[image]